# How do you listen when a checkbox in a fragment for a viewholder of an adapter ha been selected?

Tags: android

I know there is a method:

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener()
```

But I want to know when a checkbox within the adapter has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

In your list view adapter, set a OnClickListener for each item in the list.
This example listens to a button, but a checkbox is the same idea. The same
mAudioClick object is used for all items in the list.

```
private class UpdateListView extends BaseAdapter {
  @Override public View getView(int nItem, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(view==null)
      view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    setBtn(view, R.id.btnAudio, mAudioClick, "PLAY");
    return(view);
  }

  private void setBtn(View view, int ctrlID, View.OnClickListener listener, String text) {
    Button ctrl= (Button)view.findViewById(ctrlID);
    ctrl.setText(text);
    ctrl.setOnClickListener(listener);
  }
}

private class AudioClick implements View.OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    View item= (View)view.getParent();
    int nItem= mListBox.getPositionForView(item);
    mPlayer.play();
  }
}
```